# How to use enum as an object key?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How to use enum as an object key?

**Global enum**

```
export enum TableType {
    RawMedias = 'raw-medias',
    Datasets = 'datasets',
    VideosDst = 'videos-dst',
  }
```

**VideoDstPage** (parent component)

```
<VideosDstTable data={RAW_MEDIA_DATA} type={TableType.VideosDst} />
```

**VideosDstTable.tsx**

```
interface IVideosDstTableProps {
  type: TableType;
}

const tableHeaders = {
  [TableType.RawMedias]: [
    { id: 1, name: 'Name' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Status' },
  ],
  [TableType.Datasets]: [
    { id: 1, name: 'Name' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Status' },
  ],
  [TableType.VideosDst]: [
    { id: 1, name: 'Name' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Status' },
  ],
};

// ...some code
<Table tableHeaders={tableHeaders[type]}> // here's error
```

error

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any'
> can't be used to index type

**Table.tsx**

```
interface ITableProps {
  children: JSX.Element;
  tableHeaders: {
    id: number;
    name: string;
  }[];
}
```

Comment: where is the declaration of `type`?

Comment: Please provide an example in playground